# PhoneGap deviceready event not firing

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm developing a web application using [PhoneGap 1.5.0](http://phonegap.com/) but I'm unable to fire `deviceready` event.

The `cordova-1.5.0.js` I'm using was located at `PhoneGap 1.5.0\lib\android\` and I'm testing at several Android devices without success.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Device Properties Example</title>    
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.5.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">    

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        alert("onDeviceReady");
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="deviceProperties">Loading device properties...</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you suggest I check the error log?

Comment: Through Android Logcat. Connect your device to the computer and you will get the logs of your device. Also tell me which OS version are you trying it on?

Comment: I figured it out what's wrong, I was testing this example on a mobile browser without success but worked fine when I tested it as an application. Now I'm confused because I've used PhoneGap geolocation in another example and worked fine on a mobile browser. Could you please enlight me? :)

Comment: So you are saying that you opened the above html page on the mobile's web browser?If yes then It will not work for sure. You Need to Open it as an application... Secondly could you explain how you used Phonegap geolocation on a mobile browser?

Comment: I thought I was using PhoneGap features but actually I was using W3C Geolocation API, thanks for the explanations.

Comment: Yeah, the W3C Geolocation API is implemented in most modern browsers so that is what you were using. That's actually what we use in PhoneGap as well on iOS and Android versions that support the W3C implementation as it saves us some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all You need to test it as an application and not on the web browser.
Secondly if you want to use geolocation then you can use it like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Wait for PhoneGap to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// PhoneGap is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
}

// onSuccess Geolocation
//
function onSuccess(position) {
    var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
    element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '           + position.coords.latitude              + '<br />' +
                        'Longitude: '          + position.coords.longitude             + '<br />' +
                        'Altitude: '           + position.coords.altitude              + '<br />' +
                        'Accuracy: '           + position.coords.accuracy              + '<br />' +
                        'Altitude Accuracy: '  + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy      + '<br />' +
                        'Heading: '            + position.coords.heading               + '<br />' +
                        'Speed: '              + position.coords.speed                 + '<br />' +
                        'Timestamp: '          + new Date(position.timestamp)          + '<br />';
}

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
//
function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

i never could get cordova-1.5.0 to fire deviceready as expected on android (api 8).. no problem after switching to 1.6.1, however.